# How to define a command that could generate similar environments just as \newtheorem does?

Tags: macros, environments, theorems, tikz-styles

It's well known that the LaTeX built-in command `\newtheorem` could generate a series of the theorem environments that are similar: they share the same theme of layout style but differ in their name and counter style etc.

I defined a colored text box, which is used to output a fancy style of class note, using Ti*k*Z recently. Although the specific style satisfied me myself, it also brought me some kind of inconvenience. Since I want to put definition, lemma, and conclusion, for example, into different but similar styles, I have to define such environments one by one, by using over ten lines of code.

MWE is here:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathrsfs,amsfonts}

\usetikzlibrary{shapes,decorations}
\definecolor{bule}{RGB}{18,29,57}
\definecolor{bablue}{RGB}{248,248,248}
\definecolor{main}{RGB}{127,191,51}
\definecolor{seco}{RGB}{0,145,215}
\definecolor{thid}{RGB}{180,27,131}

%define the style of tikz newthemsty
\tikzstyle{newthemsty} 
          =[draw=seco, fill=blue!10,very thick,rectangle,
           rounded corners, inner sep=10pt, inner ysep=20pt]
\tikzstyle{newthemstytitle}
          =[fill=seco, text=blue!10]

%%define the "newthem" environment
\newcounter{Newthem}[chapter]
\renewcommand{\theNewthem}{\thechapter.\arabic{Newthem}}
\NewEnviron{newthem}[1][{}]{%
\noindent\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[newthemsty] (box){
     \begin{minipage}{0.93\columnwidth}
        \sffamily\BODY
     \end{minipage}};
\node[newthemstytitle,right=10pt] at (box.north west){
     \bfseries\textsf{Theorem \stepcounter{Newthem}\theNewthem\; #1}};
\node[newthemstytitle, rounded corners] at (box.east) {$\clubsuit$};
\end{tikzpicture}
}[\par\vspace{.5\baselineskip}]

\begin{document}

\begin{newthem}
    test
\end{newthem}

\end{document}
```

And its output:

> [image]

If I want a command that could define such an environment and I'm able to modify the color (of background and the edge), the font shape(italic or upright) and series(bold or not), the name in the label (say 'theorem' here) and the counter (within or without another counter), what should I do?

Any clues or hints would be appreciated.

Comment: Have a look at `tcolorbox` and `mdframed` before trying to reinvent the wheel: those packages provide ways to define new theorem styles in the way you like.

Comment: @egerg I do know these two packages provide interfaces to define fancy text box, but in fact, I need to use a `\newtheorem`-like command to define other things. Hence, how to create such a command is what I need. Could you help me? Vote up to your comment and thank you for the metaphor about wheel. `:)`

Comment: Take a look at `tcolorbox` manual, section 8, p.155., for example.

Comment: See also here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/120454/theorem-with-separate-tikz-environments-for-header-and-body

Comment: What other things? If those packages could solve this problem, it isn't clear to me what kind of solution you need. That is, how do these other things differ from the problem statement you gave? How, that is, would a solution to this problem help with those if mdframed/tcolorbox can solve this problem but not those? I guess I just find the question confusing now, although the initial question itself seemed perfectly clear.

Answer (score 2):

What you want to do is to wrap your code inside another macro that
will take a name and some settings to control the color and style.  Here I'm trying to roughly mimic `\newtheorem` and `\theoremstyle`.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathrsfs,amsfonts}
\usepackage{xparse}

\usetikzlibrary{shapes,decorations}
\definecolor{bule}{RGB}{18,29,57}
\definecolor{bablue}{RGB}{248,248,248}
\definecolor{main}{RGB}{127,191,51}
\definecolor{seco}{RGB}{0,145,215}
\definecolor{thid}{RGB}{180,27,131}


\newcommand{\newfancytheoremstyle}[5]{%
  \tikzset{#1/.style={draw=#3, fill=#2,very thick,rectangle,
      rounded corners, inner sep=10pt, inner ysep=20pt}}
  \tikzset{#1title/.style={fill=#3, text=#2}}
  \expandafter\def\csname #1headstyle\endcsname{#4}
  \expandafter\def\csname #1bodystyle\endcsname{#5}
}

\newfancytheoremstyle{fancythrm}{blue!10}{seco}{\bfseries\sffamily}{\sffamily}

\makeatletter
\DeclareDocumentCommand{\newfancytheorem}{ O{\@empty} m m m O{fancythrm} }{%
  % define the counter for the theorem
  \ifx#1\@empty
    \newcounter{#2}
  \else
    \newcounter{#2}[#1]
    \numberwithin{#2}{#1}
  \fi
  %% define the "newthem" environment
  \NewEnviron{#2}[1][{}]{%
    \noindent\centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \node[#5] (box){
        \begin{minipage}{0.93\columnwidth}
          \csname #5bodystyle\endcsname \BODY~##1
        \end{minipage}};
      \node[#5title, right=10pt] at (box.north west){
        {\csname #5headstyle\endcsname #3 \stepcounter{#2}\csname the#2\endcsname\; ##1}};
      \node[#5title, rounded corners] at (box.east) {#4};
    \end{tikzpicture}
  }[\par\vspace{.5\baselineskip}]
}
\makeatother

% Define new styles
% \newfancytheoremstyle{<name>}{inner color}{outer color}{head style}{body style}
\newfancytheoremstyle{fancydef}{green!10}{green}{\itshape\sffamily}{\sffamily}

% Define some new environments
% \newfancytheorem[<number within>]{<name>}{<head>}{<symbol>}[<style>]
\newfancytheorem[chapter]{newthem}{Theorem}{$\clubsuit$}
\newfancytheorem[section]{newcor}{Corollary}{$\heartsuit$}

\newfancytheorem{newdef}{Definition}{$\spadesuit$}[fancydef]

\begin{document}

\begin{newthem}
    test
\end{newthem}

\begin{newcor}
  test
\end{newcor}

\begin{newdef}
  test
\end{newdef}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Use the `\newfancytheoremstyle` macro to define a style (colors and fonts) and
`\newfancytheorem` to define a new environment.  I'm using `xparse` to
deal with the multiple option arguments.  Note that the argument of the "inner"
environment is referred to with `##1` instead of `#1`.